# Looping "next" button in JavaScript for images

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to illustrate the process of performing certain Math operations in a web page.  These will range from very simple Mathematics up to, potentially, very advanced (e.g. illustrations for Abstract Algebra).  I would like to do all of these, regardless of complexity, in a single format.  I think the most reasonable solution is to have an image (hand-drawn) that renders, along with a "next" button that renders the next image until it reaches the end, where it cycles back to the start.  I'm very open to other strategies that can handle symbolic, graphical, diagrammatic, and other representations.

If I do indeed use simple images in sequence, cycled by a "next" button, then the best way that I've found, so that this will work server-side, is to save all image files for a given sequence with a base name like "sum1.png" indexed from 1 through all of the images.  When the end of the sequence is reached, I produce an image that yields an error, I test for the error, and cycle back to 1.

I got this implementation to work when I write the JavaScript in `<script>` tags, but I've been trying to generalize it to an external .js file.  The problem I've been running into is that, when you create an HTML button, the function doesn't seem to accept arguments--or at least, I'm not sure how you can give it arguments.

Here is the code I have written.

```
<html><head><script src="imgLoad.js"></script>
    <body>
    <p><button onclick="nxtBtn()">Next</button></p>
    <div id = "canvas1">
        <canvas id="test"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script style = "text/javascript">
        slideShow("test", "sum");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where the contents of `imgLoad.js` is

```
// Produce an Image() object with filename name+ind+".jpg".
function initImg(name, ind) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = name + ind + ".jpg";
    return img;
}

// Draw image img to context ctx.
function draw(ctx, img) {
    if (!img.complete) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            draw(can, img);
        }, 50);
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 200,200);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200,200);
}

// Button function
function nxtBtn() {
    //not sure what to put here
}

// Set up the "slideshow", i.e. draw the first image called name 
// to the canvas canID.
function slideShow(canId, name) {
    var can = document.getElementById(canId);
    can.width = 300;
    can.height = 300;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var img = initImg(name,1);
    draw(ctx, img);
}
```

What I (think I) need to be able to do is give the button function the index of the current image so that it can try to draw the next one or, if that fails, cycle back to the start.  But I don't know of any way to give the button function this information.

---

It was suggested in the comments that the `onclick` function can take arguments.  I've never seen how that could be implemented so made my best guess about how it would go.  The result is below, it doesn't work.

```
<html><head><script src="imgLoad.js"></script>
    <body>
    <p><button onclick="nxtBtn(ctx, name, ind)">Next</button></p>
    <div id = "canvas1">
        <canvas id="test"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script style = "text/javascript">
        slideShow("test", "sum");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

where the contents of `imgLoad.js` is

```
// Produce an Image() object with filename name+ind+".jpg".
function initImg(name, ind) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = name + ind + ".jpg";
    return img;
}

// Draw image img to context ctx.
function draw(ctx, img) {
    if (!img.complete) {
        setTimeout( function() {
            draw(can, img);
        }, 50);
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0,0, 200,200);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 200,200);
}

// Button function
function nxtBtn(ctx, name, ind) {
    ind++;
    draw(ctx, initImg(name, ind));
}

// Set up the "slideshow", i.e. draw the first image called name 
// to the canvas canID.
function slideShow(canId, name) {
    var can = document.getElementById(canId);
    can.width = 300;
    can.height = 300;
    var ind = 1;
    var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    var img = initImg(name, 1);
    draw(ctx, img);
}
```

I didn't think about making it cycle since with this code the image doesn't even begin to render.

Comment: well if you have an array of the images, you could simply just do something like `image_array[ (index + 1) % image_array.length]` which would automatically loop back to the beginning if you're at the end.

Comment: @A.Lau I haven't found a way to build an array of the images that would work server-side.

Comment: Well you just said you could number 1-x so why not just keep pushing that number until you can't find one, which then restarts?

Comment: @A.Lau Right, not sure why I found that problematic.  Still it seems I have the issue of the next-button not knowing which is the current image.  How would it get the `index`?

Comment: use `indexOf`. Look it up on how to use it, it returns a number

Comment: @A.Lau I get how the `indexOf` function would work, but what would I give it?  Again, how does the next-button figure out what the current image is, if I can't give it any arguments?  How does this function interact with things outside of it, since I can't bring objects that are outside of its scope, inside the function?

Comment: so what's preventing you from giving it arguments?

Comment: @A.Lau Well, as far as I can tell it's not allowed.  Just tried my best guess about how that would go--I've never seen any instructions about how you can give the `onclick` function arguments from the rest of the script--and it didn't work.  I'll add the amended code to the question.

Comment: of course it can take arguments, you're just not giving it properly (where is ctx, name, ind defined?). see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/urx2r7z3/ If you can't seem to find a way to put an argument into it, try having a global variable then access it every time you click the next button